# how can I show operating system info through c# code

Tags: winforms, operating-system, c#-2.0

Hi
I am working on a windows application in c#. I want to show a dialog box which describes the operating system information on click of a menu item. I should achieve this programatically.

Please let me know the procedure to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `System.Environment.OSVersion`